# Was Tukaram an Advaitin philosopher?

Tags: history, advaita, saint

Did Tukaram advocate the philosophy of Advaita? Can any one give proofs that he advocated Advaita?

Comment: You meant this saint? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukaram

Comment: @Pasham Vishnu Vardhan Goud 
 There's no conclusion regarding this. He is said to be a staunch Vitthal devotee. But his works also have Advaita and Dvaita. This case might be similar to Ramakrishna Paramhamsa who had Goddess Kali as his Ista with advaitic inclination.

Answer (score 3):

The path to Self Realisation taken by Saint Tukaram was 'BhaktiMarga' or path of Devotion.

> But when he experienced God within him He said "'अणु-रेणु' या थोकडा । तुका आकाशाएवढा". This means,"I realise I am as small as an atom n it's particles as well as as limitless as sky or space".
> This shows he not only knew secrets of Dvaita philosophy but also Advait one. Because in Advaita everything is Brahman and thus both devotee n deity are also Brahman n thus are one.

Saint Tukaram was a devotee of Lord Vishnu who had spoken BhagvadGeeta in his Krishna Avatar and had taught Advait Siddhanta to Arjuna. Do you think Lord Vishnu would have restricted Tukarama from delving into pleasure of Advait experience?
Certainly not.

Saint Tukaram though being an ardent devotee of Lord Vishnu had also taught and supported Advait philosophy.

Lord Hanumana the greatest Bhakta of all time had also said to Lord Rama that through perception of Bhakti I see we are in a deity-devotee relationship but through perception of Gyana we are one.

So Although Tukaram was a devotee he had also faith n had experienced Advait state of realisation.